How to connect mariadb running inside docker compose with python script running outside docker on host machine
I wrote a docker compose file and used docker compose up -d command. Then I wrote a simple python script to connect with maria db but I get error everytime.
mariadb version in my virtual environment is 1.0.11 pip install mariadb==1.0.11
version: '3.8'

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: my_mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: myrpass  
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db1   
      MYSQL_USER: user          
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypass  
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql  
    ports:
      - "3307:3307"  
volumes:
 mariadb-data: {} 


My python code:
import mariadb

host = "mariadb"
port = 3307
user = "user"
password = "mypass"
database = "db1"

try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        host=host,
        port=port,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        database=database
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
    version = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    print(f"Connected to MariaDB server version: {version}")
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to database: {e}")
else:
    print('Connection found attempting to close it now')
    if conn:
        conn.cursor().close()
        conn.close()
finally:
    print('Code execution complete')


Error when I use mariadb as host:
Error connecting to database: Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (-3)
Code execution complete

Error when I use localhost as host:
Error connecting to database: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Code execution complete


    
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: db_mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r_pass
      MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN: 'mysql_native_password'
      # ... other environment variables
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: db_mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: r_pass
      MYSQL_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN: 'mysql_native_password'
      # ... other environment variables
    volumes:
      - mariadb-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"

volumes:
  mysql-data: {}
  mariadb-data: {}

Here is my docker-compose.yml file
Create docker compose images
docker compose up -d

Stop docker compose
docker compose down -v

Enter inside docker containers for
mysql
docker exec -it db_mysql mysql -u root -p

mariadb
docker exec -it db_mariadb mariadb -u root -p


password for mysql and mariadb
r_pass

Prerequisites if you are a ubuntu user
sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev

pip3 install mariadb==1.0.11

Python code
# Module Imports
import mariadb
import sys

# Connect to MariaDB Platform
try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="root",
        password="r_pass",
        host="<docker_ip>", # docker inspect db_mariadb
        port=3306,
        database="test"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

# Get Cursor
cur = conn.cursor()


You can use docker inspect command to know the ip address of docker
docker inspect containerid

Change the host with the ip address of docker and you are good to go.
For me I had created the database after creating container using docker exec command
docker exec -it container_name:service_name -u root -p


Thanks the inspect command helped me with ip address


If we try to connect to the MariaDB server on localhost, the client
will bypass networking and attempt to connect to the server using a
socket file in the local filesystem. However, this doesn't work when
MariaDB is running inside a container because the server's filesystem
is isolated from the host. The client can't access the socket file
which is inside the container, so it fails to connect.
Therefore connections to the MariaDB server must be made using TCP,
even when the client is running on the same machine as the server
container.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-and-using-mariadb-via-docker/#connecting-to-mariadb-from-outside-the-container
Generally, you should consider using docker networks and run your python script in a dedicated container, so both can communicate in a shared network.
